# Unable to install n in order to update node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

I tried installing n using the simple command,
when I hit enter I got an error

```
$ npm install -g n
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@8.0.0: wanted {"os":"!win32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    !win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  undefined
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

Comment: Please post the error message that you are getting. @Michael

Comment: `npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@8.0.0: wanted {"os":"!win32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})` it tells you all: windows is not supported. As per the [n docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n#supported-platforms) it only supported in macOS and Linux

Answer (score 8, accepted):

n is supported on macOS, Linux, including with Windows Subsystem for Linux, and various other unix-like systems.
n does not work in native shells on Microsoft Windows (like PowerShell), or Git for Windows BASH, or with the Cygwin DLL.

Comment: Thank you Piyush for the quick response. What do you suggest is the best way to update node.js 
I've heard of people downloading and installing node and ending up with two versions by accident.

Comment: 1) If you are using windows then directly download the nodejs installer and install it. First uninstall the old one.
2) If you are using docker or any linux based system then you can can "n" or "nvm". This will help you to main various versions for different projects. By following this way, you will be able to run multiple projects with different versions.